# Curl post to Wordpress removes my <video><source> tag

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, oauth, html5-video

I am currently posting to Wordpress from my software. I have not had any trouble passing any text or html tags through my post until now. For some reason, I am losing the `<source>` tag within my `<video>` code whenever it is posted to Wordpress.

**Here is what the content looks like that I am attempting to pass through to Wordpress.**

```
<video controls="controls" height="1440" id="248" poster="" width="1920"><source src="http://virpublisher.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/GOPR0241.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag</video>
```

**Here is the result of the post to Wordpress**

```
<video controls="controls" height="1440" id="248" poster="" width="1920">Your browser does not support the video tag</video>
```

---

I did some logging to find out exactly where I lose the `<source>` tag. Within my PHP code below, you can see where I debug for `$qParams`. Within the logging underneath, you can see that `<source>` is still visible within `[content]`. However, I seem to lose the `<source>` tag whenever I get down to this line of code `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($qParams));`. You can see this illustrated within my logging under `===RESP DEBUG===`. Could anyone help me understand why this is happening?

**An excerpt from my PHP code:**

```
$qParams    = array(
                'access_token' => $at,
                'title'=>$title,
                'content'=>$content,
                'excerpt'=>$excerpt,
                'status'=>$wpStatus,
                'categories'=>$wpCategories,
                'featured_media'=>$wpFeaturedMediaId);

Util::error_log('====ARTICLE POST PARAMS===');
Util::debugArr($qParams);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($qParams)); //I seem to lose my <source> tag here
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

Util::error_log('====RESP DEBUG===');
Util::debugArr($resp);

$resp = Util::jsonDecode($resp);
```

**Logging:**

```
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:51 America/Chicago] INFO: ====ARTICLE POST PARAMS===
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:51 America/Chicago] ==== START debugArr: ====
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:51 America/Chicago] Array(
[access_token] => fjeter5hjhiyezhrvhcy7o1mogavbmadoos5n745
[title] => Mountain Biking
[content] => <video controls="controls" height="1440" id="248" poster="" width="1920"><source src="http://virpublisher.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/GOPR0241.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag</video>
[excerpt] => 
[status] => draft
[categories] => Array
    (
    )
[featured_media] => 174
)
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:51 America/Chicago] ==== END debugArr: ====


[14-Apr-2016 14:16:53 America/Chicago] INFO: ====RESP DEBUG===
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:53 America/Chicago] ==== START debugArr: ====
[14-Apr-2016 14:16:53 America/Chicago] {"id":286,"date":"2016-04-14T19:16:53","date_gmt":null,"guid":{"rendered":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info?p=286&#038;preview_id=286","raw":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info?p=286&#038;preview_id=286"},"modified":"2016-04-14T19:16:53","modified_gmt":"2016-04-14T19:16:53","password":"","slug":"mountain-biking-2","status":"draft","type":"post","link":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info?p=286&preview_id=286","title":{"raw":"Mountain Biking","rendered":"Mountain Biking"},"content":{"raw":"<video controls=\"controls\" height=\"1440\" id=\"248\" poster=\"\" width=\"1920\">Your browser does not support the video tag<\/video>\n","rendered":"<p><video controls=\"controls\" height=\"1440\" id=\"248\" poster=\"\" width=\"1920\">Your browser does not support the video tag<\/video><\/p>\n"},"excerpt":{"raw":"","rendered":"<p>Your browser does not support the video tag<\/p>\n"},"author":1,"featured_media":174,"comment_status":"closed","ping_status":"open","sticky":false,"format":"standard","categories":[1],"tags":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/286"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"}],"about":[{"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"}],"author":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"}],"replies":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=286"}],"version-history":[{"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/286\/revisions"}],"https:\/\/api.w.org\/featuredmedia":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/174"}],"https:\/\/api.w.org\/attachment":[{"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=286"}],"https:\/\/api.w.org\/term":[{"taxonomy":"category","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=286"},{"taxonomy":"post_tag","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/virpublisher.info\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=286"}]}}
```

Comment: I would wager a bet that it is neither `http_build_query` nor cURL that is breaking the content.  Probably some HTML filtering being done by WordPress is removing it.  Maybe it's getting confused by the lack of closing tag (which is doesn't need) but nonetheless is causing it to be stripped.  What API endpoint or RPC method are you calling in WordPress?

Comment: @drew010 Sadly, I logged the http_build_query separately and that also contained the source tag. I am using OAuth Server Wordpress plugin along with REST API. It looks to happen on the response from the post. Im trying to figure out why Wordpress would do that. Whenever I manually add the video code to Wordpress and save within the UI it includes the source tag with no problem.

Comment: I've also just tried with the following format <video><source></source></video> which also stripped the source tag

Comment: I've also tried other types of tags within the <video> container such as <div></div>, <p></p>, <em></em>, and they all remain.